# IsEnabledChanged in class derived from ButtonBase

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control which inherits from the WPF class ButtonBase (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase).

I would like to define a function which will be called when the IsEnabled property in the base class is changed.

I am probably being really stupid, but I can't find an easy way to do it. (There is no function OnIsEnabledChanged function which can be overridden.)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase(v=vs.110).aspx#IsEnabledChanged) there is an IsEnabledChanged event.

Comment: I know that there is an IsEnabledChanged event, but it doesn't seem appropriate to use an event to handle a change in the base class. My question is about how best to handle it in a derived class.

Comment: @PhilJollans It’s perfectly appropriate. Why wouldn’t it be?

Comment: OK, I will try it. It may be simpler than using OverrideMetadata. However, other people have doubts about this pattern, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505851/should-my-class-subscribe-to-its-own-public-events), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031157/is-it-poor-form-for-a-c-sharp-class-to-subscribe-to-its-own-published-events) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96293/subscribing-an-object-to-its-own-events). Also Microsoft has often provided an OnXXX function which can be overridden in a derived class, but not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsEnabled  is **Dependency Property**.
So you have to override metadata, Like here:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    static MyButton()
    {
        MyButton.IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                FunctionToCallOnPropertyChange, //property changed callback 
                null, // coerce value callback 
                true, // is animation prohibited 
                UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus));
    }

    private static void FunctionToCallOnPropertyChange(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Do I have to call the OnPropertyChange function in the base class? If so, how.

Comment: you will get your button instance here DependencyObject dependencyObject. So you have to cast it to right type (MyButton) and call.